# Using a textbox or label like a button in c# visual studio

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use a label or textbox in the same way you would use a button in a c# visual studio document?

i.e. can it be selected and have a result similiar to a button being clicked?

Comment: What project type are you asking this for? WPF? Windows Forms? ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: For TextBox, do you want selecting a text or Click on text

Comment: How do you expect your user to figure out that they act like buttons?

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to use a link label. That way whenever the mouse hovers over it, the person knows that clicking on it causes an action.

```
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("you have clicked a link label");
        //or whatever action you want it to do.
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

### For `Click` Event :

You can use the [`Label.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event or [`TextBox.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.click.aspx) event

---

### For Event when Some Text is selected in the `TextBox` :

Although there is no Special Event For this, You can Utilize the [`TextBox.MouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx) event like this :

```
private void txtBox_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    TextBox txtbx = sender as TextBox;
    if (txtbx != null)
    {
        if (txtbx.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            string seltxt = txtbx.SelectedText;
            //Do Work Here with 'seltxt' variable!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use anything as a button if you wanted to, but why would you want to rather than using a button?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label_events

Everything that is a Control object in WinForms has a "Click" event that can be used. Subscribe to that event with a custom method and do what you want to do in that event. If you want the label to have a button look-and-feel I'd suggest putting a border and some hover, press and release decorations using the appropriate events.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

They have the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event also.